# Ultrassonic sensor

Tags: arduino-uno

Hi I have this ultrasonic sensor:

http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf

I use this code to read distances:

```
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(5);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
long time = pulseIn(echoPin,HIGH);
```

My question is this: in the datasheet says that the sensor will send 8 pulses at 40khz. Every pulse will take 0.000025 seconds so 8 pulses would be 200 usec.

So why the delay is only 10 usec if it should be 200usec?

Answer (score 1):

The 10us delay is just your trigger pulse HIGH phase. Refer to the timing diagram on bottom of page two in your datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

The 10 us pulse to the TRIG pin activates the ultrasonic detector. It then sends 8 pulses at 40 kHz, and finally, sends a pulse to the ECHO pin. That pulse sent to the ECHO pin has a pulse-width proportional to the distance of the nearest object.